# Swift - Vapor Using HTML

Tags: html, swift, perfect, vapor

I recently made the switch from [Perfect](https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect) to [Vapor](https://github.com/vapor/vapor).In Perfect you could do something like this without using a html file.

```
routes.add(method: .get, uri: "/", handler: {
    request, response in
    response.setHeader(.contentType, value: "text/html")
    response.appendBody(string: "<html><img src=http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg></html>")
    response.completed()
   }
)
```

In Vapor the only way I found to  return the html is to do this.How could I return html code without using a html file in vapor?

```
 drop.get("/") { request in
    return try drop.view.make("somehtmlfile.html")
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question about something also? Please edit your post and include a clear question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can build your own [Response](https://vapor.github.io/documentation/http/response.html), avoiding views completely.

```
drop.get { req in
  return Response(status: .ok, headers: ["Content-Type": "text/html"], body: "<html><img src=http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg></html>")
}
```

or

```
drop.get { req in
  let response = Response(status: .ok, body: "<html><img src=http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg></html>")
  response.headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html"
  return response
}
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't search throught the documentation fully.

Comment: The second no longer works because the subscript is not modifiable.